# Swipe Js Multiple swipes

Tags: javascript, jquery, swipe

I have multiple swipe scrollers on one page.

I used this code to create them:

```
var swipes = [];
$('.slider').each(function(i, obj) {
    swipes[i] = new Swipe(obj);
});
```

The problem is how do I access the optional second parameters eg.

```
  continuous: true,
  callback: function(index, elem) {},
  transitionEnd: function(index, elem) {}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

swipes[i].parameterName = desiredParameterValue;

Answer (score 0):

Hope my answer is still relevant. The following should work:

```
var swipes = [];
$('.slider').each(function(i, obj) {
   swipes[i] = new Swipe(obj, {
      continuous: true,
      callback: function(index, elem) {},
      transitionEnd: function(index, elem) {}
   });
});
```